# Cursor appears at center of EditBox

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an `EditBox` in which I set the input type as `textMultiLine`. The issue is that the cursor in the `EditBox` always appears at the center of the `EditBox`, But I want it to display at the top left of my EditBox.

So why this happens?

**Code for EditBox**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/notes_edit_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/img_add_notes_textbox"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:maxHeight="30dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:textColor="#121212" >
</EditText>
```

**ScreenShots**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because, by default gravity of `EditText` is `center` so just set it to `top`

```
android:gravity="top"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `android:gravity="top|left"` to your EditText